# can't include shared library in android studio

Tags: java, android, android-ndk

I'm having a hard time with including my own sqlite library (libsqliteX.so) in android studio:

I followed this [guide](https://www.sqlite.org/android/doc/trunk/www/index.wiki) and loaded [this](https://www.sqlite.org/android/zip/SQLite+Android+Bindings-cf6a31d2c9.zip?uuid=cf6a31d2c93f8872) and compiled it with latest android NDK (r10e) (i just added "APP_ABI := xxx" to the Application.mk to build also x86 and armeabi-v7a versions of it) and got this:
console output: s3.postimg.org/v83e8bwsz/ndk_build.jpg (cant post more than 2 links :D).

After that I have created a new app in android studio (v1.2.1.1) and create a new jnilibs-folder where I copied my .so files: s17.postimg.org/7vvvsao67/jni_Libs.jpg

I didn't change the build.gradle (gradle version 1.2.3) or anything, just compiled my app and the libraries are included in the apk (opened the .../app/build/outputs/apk/apk-debug.apk with winzip and there is a lib-folder with the libsqliteX.so files).

But now I don't know how to use that library in my project. I'm not able to add the line `import org.sqlite.database...;` (cant resolve symbol 'sqlite'), I'm not able to add that libraries in Project Structure -> Dependencies
(only the default depencies that are also in the build.gradle are there:

```
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
```

and if I just load the library with `System.loadLibrary("sqliteX");` 
I got this error at runtime:

```
05-29 03:21:54.248    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff D/dalvikvm﹕ Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.thele.geostuff-1/libsqliteX.so 0x416f6428
05-29 03:21:54.288    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff E/SQLiteConnection﹕ Unable to find class org/sqlite/database/sqlite/SQLiteCustomFunction
05-29 03:21:54.288    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff W/dalvikvm﹕ JNI WARNING: JNI method called with exception pending
05-29 03:21:54.288    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff W/dalvikvm﹕ in Ljava/lang/Runtime;.nativeLoad:(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/ClassLoader;Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/String; (GetFieldID)
05-29 03:21:54.288    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff W/dalvikvm﹕ Pending exception is:
05-29 03:21:54.297    3450-3450/com.example.thele.geostuff I/dalvikvm﹕ java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/database/sqlite/SQLiteCustomFunction
```

(changing dalvik to art throws a similar error (cant find the class))

I applied different methods to make it work (invalidate caches/restart, created a .jar file out of the .so file) but it didn't help.
What I'm doing wrong?

---

Edit:

The complete build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.thele.geostuff"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.1.1'
}
```

Comment: can you show your complete build.gradle?

Comment: @helleye edited the first post

Comment: Have you tried adding         `sourceSets.main {
            jniLibs.srcDir 'main/jniLibs'
        }` inside build.gradle?

Comment: same error (Unable to find class org/sqlite/.../SQLiteCustomFunction)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me the error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/sqlite/database/sqlite/SQLiteCustomFunction
```

Seems to be a Java layer error, not a C level error. Because the *.c files doesn't have package/folder structure (like "org/sqlite/database...").

So my best guess is, some .class file are not in your apk. If I were you I'd use 7zip/winrar to unzip the apk and check if the **org.sqlite.database.sqlite.SQLiteCustomFunction** is there.

Actually, I believe the .so is successfully loaded.

```
Added shared lib /data/app-lib/com.example.thele.geostuff-1/libsqliteX.so 0x416f6428
```

Comment: thanks! i added the org-folder in SQLite_Android_Bindings-xxx\src to .../app/src/main/java and its working now. (didnt know that it is necessary)